# ReflectionFunction return type is null on built in functions

Tags: php, reflection

Using the following reflection on built in functions, makes the return type always be null.

```
$reflectionFunction = new \ReflectionFunction('strtoupper');

// $reflectionFunction->getReturnType() returns null
```

While `getDocComment` does not work, how to get the return type of built in functions. I know this is expected, as the documentation [describes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getreturntype.php). It is a question about how to proceed from here, to calculate the return type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you have to use a map for this, PHPStan has a decent one that you could lean on: [Phpstans Version](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan/blob/master/src/Reflection/SignatureMap/functionMap.php)

It's originally derived from this one from [Phan version](https://github.com/phan/phan/blob/master/src/Phan/Language/Internal/FunctionSignatureMap.php).

I don't think either is available as separate packages so you might have to depend on the full project, or do what `PHPStan` did an make and maintain your own copy. You could also talk to them about spinning it off in to a separate package. The good news is that it is really simple to use, see the helper classes in the same folder as the files.